# What is the appstore id needed for creating a flurry campaign link?

Tags: flurry

I'm trying to set up a flurry campaign link that will track how often someone installed my app  from a link on Facebook. One of the fields that must be filled out while doing this is `Apple AppStore ID Required`. What is the appstore id? I've tried using my application identifier `com.me.myapp` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is in Apple Store you will find download link as below

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/medzam-headache/id739652713?mt=8

From above link. 739652713 is the Apple Store ID.

You will not have AppStoreId If you are not having your App at Apple Store..

Hope it Helps you....!

Answer (score 1):

You get your *AppStoreID* even **BEFORE** publishing app at AppStore. For example for configuring Firebase dynamic links you need to know your AppStoreId.

1. Go to *App Store Connect*
2. Click on your *application*
3. In *General* select *App Information*
4. Get your value from field `Apple ID`
   [image]